# Can you install mySQL Cluster for free?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, distributed

Can you install mySQL Cluster for free? 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/7.0.html#win32

This will only give you the .zip files. But it doesn't contain the MSI installer. without the installer, how do you even have contents under
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 7.0\data?

I think you have to pay for the MSI in order to install mySQL Cluster properly right?

I tried to unzip the files, follow the instructions, updated the config files, but never work.

Can someone confirm? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options. If you don't mind having an SSH server running on your Windows machines then you can use the new auto-installer from labs.mysql.com.

An alternative is to follow the instructions from http://downloads.mysql.com/tutorials/cluster/mysql_wp_cluster_quickstart_windows.pdf - basically you just manually copy the data files.

Andrew.

Comment: hi andrew, thanks. I read the pdf briefly, it looks like you can install MySQL Cluster on a single machine right?

instead of having different IPs, I think the following entries in config file is what "simulates" the different data node, please let me know.

[ndbd]
hostname=localhost
NodeId=3
[ndbd]
hostname=localhost
NodeId=4

......


Thanks

Comment: Correct. Note that there alternative resources for setting up Cluster - including accross multiple hosts - I just wanted to point out how to handle the bootstrapping of the mysql database.